# Git Pre-Commit Hook Adding File After Commit

Tags: mysql, git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I am attempting to dump a mysql database and add the .sql dump file to the staging area using a pre-commit hook so it can then be included in the commit (on Windows Server 2012 R2/IIS).  The following code dumps the database nicely, but after I commit it still shows the be.sql file in the staging area...sometimes(?) - it seems to be adding the file to staging AFTER committing(?).  This is a pre-commit hook so I have no idea why it may be adding the file after the commit takes place:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Dump Database
/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/MySQL/MySQL\ Server\ 5\.7/bin/mysqldump.exe -u root --skip-extended-insert be > /c/inetpub/wwwroot/directory/be/be.sql

# Add Database
cd /c/inetpub/wwwroot/directory/be
git add be.sql
```

The behavior is a bit strange - I will see be.sql is still in the staging area so I will make a commit.  If I git status afterwards the tree is clean.  If I commit again and git status it will display the be.sql file in the staging index as modified (I didn't modify it).  And back and forth it goes.  I just want it to dump the .sql file, add the .sql file to the staging index, THEN commit so every time the staging index is clean.  Any ideas as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to add "exit 0" on last line (saw it in few "internets" examples)

Comment: Your script has a "cd" in it, which moves it from the current directory—which is a bit tricky in Git hooks—to some *other* directory. But at the same time, you *do not* override various Git environment variables, which means that those set by Git to direct Git to specific repository, index file, and/or work-tree paths may still direct Git to specific (and now potentially wrong) such files. I'm not sure whether Git-for-Windows does anything weird and special, vs "normal" Git, but normal Git winds up setting the variables based on arguments *between* `git` and the sub-command, plus ... [cont'd]

Comment: the *commit* hooks (pre-commit, edit-commit-msg) are run with `GIT_INDEX_FILE` set. Fortunately, modifying the index file (staging area) is explicitly allowed in a pre-commit hook, ever since Git version 1.5.4 anyway. However, the path may be relative, and if so and you are cd-ing to a different location, you will need to adjust it.

Comment: Hi Torek, thanks for the notes.  I already answered the question on this thread, I am unable to accept it as the answer for another day which is why this issue is still open.

Comment: Hi Torek, I wanted to write again and thank you for your comment.  It didn't solve my initial problem, but the other day it started happening again and it was a different issue related to how the synchronization of files (including the hooks) was resulting in files re-syncing into the directory they were just committed in, thereby placing it in the staging index.  When I came back to this thread and read your comment it triggered me to re-check the directories the hooks were reading, and I noticed the sync was overwriting the correct directory.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
git commit -m "Message" --allow-empty
```

when making the commit appears to have worked.  It seems as if git needs other staged changes in order for the hook to work.  So it was basically not making the commit, but still dumping the be.sql file, which would then show up in the staging index as modified the next time around because the date had changed.  In order to allow the commit to fully go through regardless of whether or not there were other staged changes I used the --allow-empty option, which allows a commit with nothing in the staged index.